# How to set user picked option in PHP form

Tags: php, html

I have an drop down option select of the 50 states that the user must choose. I'm trying to get the form to set itself as whatever the specific user chose. I have an info array that contains their info, including the state they chose as $state. All the other info echos properly but the drop down menu has been giving me some trouble. Any help would be appreciated!

I currently have

```
`echo '<p> Name: <input type = "text" name ="name" value ="'.$name. '" /> </p>';
```

Properly prints name the user input

```
`echo '<p> State: 
         <select name = "state">
            <option value=\"'.$state.'"\ selected="selected></option>
            <option value="Alabama"> Alabama </option>
            <option value="Alaska"> Alaska</option>
```

(has all 50 states) defaults to blank option`

Answer (score 2):

To set the selected option in a select box you can do the following:

```
<select name="state">
    <option value="Alabama" <?php if($state == 'Alabama'){ echo 'selected' } ?>>Alabama</option>
    <option value="Alaska" <?php if($state == 'Alaska'){ echo 'selected' } ?>>Alaska</option>
    ....
</select>
```

Comment: Just fixed the syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select name = "state">
       <option value="<?php echo $state ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $state ?></option>
       <option value="Alabama"> Alabama </option>
       <option value="Alaska"> Alaska</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated!